# SQL - Как выбрать строки с наибольшими датами

Tags: sql

Есть таблица - "Tests", хранит информацию о тестируемых приборах:

```
CREATE TABLE Tests (
  Test_id int  NOT NULL,
  Test_Start_Date DATETIME NOT NULL, 
  Device_Name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
);
```

В Device_Name (Номер тестируемого прибора) значения повторяются (прибор могут тестировать несколько раз).

Нужно отсортировать так чтобы оставить только уникальные номера приборов с максимальной датой.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос должен вывести:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал запрос:

```
SELECT Device_Name, MAX(Test_Start_Date) 
FROM Tests 
group by Device_Name
```

но он показал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: SELECT Device_Name, MAX(Test_Start_Date) **as Test_Start_Date** FROM Tests group by Device_Name
Вот так попробуйте, если вас напрягает "отсутствует имя столбца" =)

Answer (score 1):

Такое бывает, когда вы не называете столбец, в котором используется функция.

Вы можете назвать столбец через [алиас `as`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp), например:

```
SELECT Device_Name, MAX(Test_Start_Date) as last_test_start_date
FROM Tests 
group by Device_Name
```

Если же вам нужна целиком строка с последним испытанием, то можно использовать такой запрос:

```
select t.*
from tests t 
    join (SELECT Device_Name, MAX(Test_Start_Date) as last_test_start_date
          FROM Tests 
          group by Device_Name) m 
        on t.device_name = m.device_name and t.test_start_date = m.last_test_start_date
```

Comment: Зачем во втором запросе join ? разве не лучше будет просто перечислить все поля? или разницы в производительности не будет совсем? Почему связь не через id?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а как вы собираетесь перечислить все поля, если по id не сделаете группировку? Или я немного не понял ход ваших мыслей. Связь не через id, ибо пока непонятна структура таблицы автора с четким пониманием, что чем больше id - тем позже дата.

Comment: Связь по айди я про это **on t.device_name = m.device_name and t.test_start_date = m.last_test_start_date** зачем связь по двум полям которые к тому же могут быть не уникальны( и автор это указал!!)

Comment: Про все поля - ваш джоин с вложенным запросом делает ровно то что вместо перечисления всех полей вы можете использовать **t.***, в случае же если его не использовать придется перечислить все нужные поля поименно. **Test_id, Device_Name, MAX(Test_Start_Date) as Test_Start_Date** будет тоже самое что в вашем примере но без лишнего join, если у автора более 3х полей - нужно перечилить их все

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков 1. связь по id лишь в том случае, когда таблица упорядочена (да, связь по id безусловно лучше). Тут она возможно тестовая, о чем я уже сказал в предыдущем комментарии, поэтому здесь идёт соединение по 2 столбцам. Неуникальны названия девайсов, с учетом того, что время тут до секунды, то можно и поюзать этот случай.Запрос с `join` используется для вытаскивания все строки. Запрос с агрегированием поможет получить лишь последнюю дату и ровным счетом больше ничего, если в таблице будет больше информации. Надеюсь, я исчерпывающе ответил на ход своих мыслей:)

Comment: Все, я понял где дурак и с какой целью этот join =)